# How to activate an Anaconda environment from the command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, subprocess, anaconda

I'm trying to access a module which is installed in a virtual environment, but the problem I've run into is that I can't activate my environment from the command line (Windows cmd).

Is there a command to activate an environment from the command line?

It is for a Python project. So if you can find a solution to open the Anaconda command line and execute commands there, it would be also great.

Comment: source activate [env] or conda activate [env] edit: make sure conda is in your windows path.

Comment: It isn't in my path, how to add it?

Comment: Did you read the [install instructions](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html). Edit additionally IIRC during installation on windows there is a box you should tick to add it to path.

Comment: No I didn't, but it's already installed. How can I add it to my pat?

Comment: You can add it to path by going to Edit environment variables and then adding conda ex to path. First you should locate where you installed conda executable.

Comment: However redoing the installation with the box ticked will be easier.

Comment: So, what does `where /r "C:\" conda.exe` says in cmd?

Comment: I get a lot of lines output, but I think I need this one: `C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe`

Comment: Where is `conda` installed?

Comment: Don't put Anaconda on your `PATH` (it is not recommended by Anaconda). Instead, use the Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: But can I open the Anaconda prompt with python and execute commands in it?

Comment: No, you run Python from within the Anaconda Prompt. The Anaconda Prompt is opened from, e.g., the Start Menu.

Comment: I think you don't get it... I want to write a script which accesses the command line (CMD or anaconda)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: Can you suggest a site?

Comment: This question is very specific and should be re-opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an environment:
conda create --name myenv

NOTE: Replace myenv with the environment name.

When conda asks you to proceed, type y:

proceed ([y]/n)?[for  more detail click this](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

about activate [this may help](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/)

to add anaconda to path

In Windows, you will have to set the path to the location where you installed Anaconda3 to.

For me, I installed anaconda3 into C:\Anaconda3. Therefore you need to add C:\Anaconda3 as well as C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\ to your path variable, e.g. set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts.

Comment: I already have an environment.

Comment: When I run the 'path' command, I can use the `conda` command but i get an error when i run `conda activate`, it's to big to post here but i says that my shell has not properly been configured for conda activate. the solutions provided in the error are for linux... what now?

Comment: this worked for me in a .cmd:    
`set PATH=`_<conda base install folder>_`\Scripts;`_<conda base install folder>_`;%PATH%`    
`call conda.bat init cmd.exe`    
`call conda.bat activate `_<desired environment name>_    
_<do stuff in the env>_

Answer (score 1):

type `conda` in cmd
You should be in the conda environment.

If it isn't, you have to add Anaconda to your environment path. You can try `where conda` to see where your installation is at.

Comment: conda isn't in my path and `where conda` doesn't return anything usefull, how can I add conda to my path?

Answer (score 0):

If windows cmd doesn't recognise conda, open Anaconda prompt and write the following command:

```
activate <env_name>
```

Then, you will be seeing your prompt with your current environment in parentheses like this:

```
(env_name) $
```

For detailed info, click [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: That's not what i want, I want to open my environment using the command line.

Comment: By environment do you mean your virtual env or the deafult conda env?

Comment: For either of the case, add conda to your environment variable (user variable). It generally is _C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_ but check for yours. And ProgramData is a hidden folder.

Comment: how should I name the environment variable

Comment: and do i need to use the path to the \Anacond folder or to the conda.exe file?

Comment: You don't have to name it. In the user variable "path", just add an entry for the Anaconda folder. That will do it!!

Comment: Thx for the support!

Comment: You are answering a different question. The question is about starting a conda environment from cmd.exe and specifically not the anaconda prompt.

Comment: Since this came up when I websearched the issue, a note for posterity: After adding "my_install_location/Anaconda3/condabin" to the PATH environment variable, I can use conda commands in cmd.exe, without the Anaconda Prompt. (This works through the .bat-files "conda.bat" and "activate.bat" that are in condabin.)

Comment: Does not answer the question that was asked